# node.js Buffer binary output is different

Tags: node.js, sockets, binary

This has me very confused. I have the following socket server (simplified) in node.js:

```
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        var replyData = new Buffer('78780E00C425BA53269830303000006C2D0D0A',
            'hex').toString('binary');
        socket.end(replyData);
    });
}).listen(config.port);
```

What I would expect it to reply to any client is the binary as specified in hexadecimal in the buffer, but it actually replies: 78780E00C38425C2BA5326C298303030006C2D0D0A

This is similar, but not exactly what it should send. What am I missing?

Comment: Please show us your code on the client you use to print/inspect the response. :)

Comment: @rdrey: I did not write any client code. I simply did `wget http://localhost:9880` and looked at the file using a hex editor (Okteta in my case)

Comment: Oops, my bad. I thought this was a Socket.io question. Your `wget` is a perfectly reasonable way to test this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple, just pass a `Buffer` directly to your socket:

```
var net = require('net');

net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    socket.end(new Buffer('78780E00C425BA53269830303000006C2D0D0A', 'hex'));
 });
}).listen(config.port);
```

**EDIT**: just reread your question and figured out your problem was not getting the data as binary. Nonetheless, my code works for me:

```
laurent ~/dev/test $ wget http://localhost:3001 --output-document=data
laurent ~/dev/test $ hexdump data
0000000 78 78 0e 00 c4 25 ba 53 26 98 30 30 30 00 00 6c
0000010 2d 0d 0a                                       
0000013
```

Tell me if you get something different.